# How to use custom fonts in TinyMCE using tinymce-vue package for VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, tinymce

I'm trying to use custom fonts stored in my assets/fonts folder with TinyMCE, but it seems like it can't render the font, except for the format selector. The content doesn't display the font correctly, although the font selector shows the font is being applied (in the title, for example).

Here's the code so far:

```
<template>
  <tinymce-editor
    :key="id"
    :initial-value="initialValue"
    :resize="false"
    :init="{
      selector: 'textarea#format-custom',
      height: height,
      plugins: 'table wordcount link lists',
      menubar : false,
      statusbar : false,
      toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic| styleselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | numlist bullist | fontselect',
      content_css: [ '//www.tiny.cloud/css/codepen.min.css' ],
      content_style: 'body { font-family: Roboto Light; font-size: 16px; }' + '.left { text-align: left; }' + 'img.left { float: left; }' + 'table.left { float: left; }' + '.right { text-align: right; }' + 'img.right { float: right; }' + 'table.right { float: right; }' + '.center { text-align: center; }' + 'img.center { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }' + 'table.center { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }' + '.full { text-align: justify; }' + 'img.full { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }' + 'table.full { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }' + '.bold { font-weight: bold; }' + '.italic { font-style: italic; }' + '.underline { text-decoration: underline; }' + '.title { font-family: Raleway Bold; font-size: 26px; }' + '.subtitle { font-family: Roboto Medium; font-size: 20px; }',
      formats: {
        alignleft: { selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'left' },
        aligncenter: { selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'center' },
        alignright: { selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'right' },
        alignfull: { selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'full' },
        bold: { inline: 'span', classes: 'bold' }, italic: { inline: 'span', classes: 'italic' },
        titleformat: { inline: 'span', attributes: { title: 'Title'} , classes: 'title', },
        subtitleformat: { inline: 'span', attributes: { title: 'SubTitle'} , classes: 'subtitle' } },
      style_formats: [ { title: 'Title', format: 'titleformat' }, { title: 'SubTitle', format: 'subtitleformat' } ]
    }"
    api-key="no-api-key"
    model-events="change keydown blur focus paste"
    @input="handleInput"
    @error="handleError"
  />
</template>

<script>
import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue'

export default {
  components: {
    'tinymce-editor': Editor
  },
  props: {
    initialValue: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    id: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    height: {
      type: String,
      default: '100%'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput (value) {
      this.$emit('input', value)
    },
    handleError (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here's a print:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use custom fonts you need to:

1. Load them into TinyMCE via `content_css`
2. Include the fonts via the `font_formats` configuration option:  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#font_formats

You appear to be loading the CSS from the TinyMCE demo site:

```
content_css: [ '//www.tiny.cloud/css/codepen.min.css' ],
```

This is likely not something you want to do as our demo CSS would likely not be appropriate for your web site/application.  I would change that to use an appropriate CSS for your site.  In that CSS you can load a custom font.  For example:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');
```

***Note:***  *The reason the TinyMCE menu can render the font is you are likely loading the font on the page that includes TinyMCE but not in TinyMCE itself.  The editor content is in its own `iframe` but the menus are part of the main page.  If you inspect the DOM you will be able to see this layout.  Using `content_css` allows you to inject CSS into the editor's `iframe`.*

Comment: I have a css file where I imported the fonts, in the same folder as the template file. What is the right path I should put in the 'content_css' property to point to it? It can't seem to get it right...

Comment: I can't tell you the answer to that as I have no idea how your application is deployed.  The `content_css` setting is run in the browser so whatever path the browser needs to find the CSS file is the path you need to use.

Comment: Well, when the application is deployed, all the css files are incorporated in the html file with <style> tags, so the file I'm trying to put in 'content_css' is no longer a file, it's part of the code. So, I don't know how make this work.

Comment: TinyMCE expects/needs that to be a file it can load into the iFrame.  Alternatively you can use `content_style` to pass specific CSS into the editor via the TinyMCE configuration.   Most people find `content_css` easier to use.